# still Not able to Hide Horizontal Scrollbar of FlowLayoutPanel in WinForms Apps

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I am not able to hide the Horizontal Scroll-bar of my FlowLayout panel. I am adding this panel dynamically.

I have read the below 3 posts on stack overflow. but not able to get success.

[flowlayoutpanel and horizontal scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299754/flowlayoutpanel-and-horizontal-scrollbar-issue)

[How do I disable the horizontal scrollbar in a Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489273/how-to-disable-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-panel)

[Scrolling panel using horizontal scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452612/scrolling-panel-using-horizontal-scroll-bar)

I have tried the following code.

```
TableLayoutPanel pannel = new TableLayoutPanel();
 pannel.Parent = pnlChart;
 pannel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 pannel.AutoScroll = true;
 pannel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
```

Comment: For me it was as simple as `AutoScroll = false`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197452/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrollbar-for-table-panel-in-winforms)

```
int vertScrollWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

pannel.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, vertScrollWidth, 0);
```